# How to get list of AWS users in EKS Cluster using SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

How do I get list of users in AWS EKS Cluster using Node AWS SDK?

```
async function userHasAccessToEksCluster(user, clusterArn) {


// Get the list of IAM policies that are attached to the user
  const policiesResult = await iam.listAttachedUserPolicies({ UserName: user.UserName }).promise();
  const policies = policiesResult.AttachedPolicies;
  // Get the policy document
  return policies.some(async (policy) => {
    const policyDocument = await iam.getPolicy({ PolicyArn: policy.PolicyArn }).promise();
    console.log(policyDocument);
  });

  // Check if any of the policies grant the user permission to access the EKS cluster
}
```

how can I check from users list to check if they have EKS permissions?

Comment: Why do you want that? IAM policies can be extremely complex, they can grant permissions based on IPs, VPCs, the current time, ... you should not ever need to evaluate them yourself, IAM takes care of that.

Comment: Are there any EKS sdk commands that can give me list of users?

Comment: Not best practice to assign users policy to individual users, look into using a GROUP to assign all users with EKS permission and let the assume the EKS role.  https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/091_iam-groups/create-iam-groups/